# My scheduled job randomly stops working

Tags: scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

I checked debug logs and didnt find any issues but when i went to apex job i found that errormessage 'Java Heap Space'. How to fix that and what can be the problem. Job junner like over a year without any problems but now i'm getting this message randomly;[image]

Comment: If you run this job manually by calling it from Anon Apex, does it complete? If so, can you monitor limits to see what may be getting close?

Comment: I would not expect to see a "Java Heap Exception" if you violate governor limits, but rather see the governor limit violation message. I suggest two things: 1. Make a trivial change to the code (e.g. some comments) to force it to recompile and if that doesn't stop this happening (or reveal some code issue due to other changes made on the org since you last deployed this code) 2. Raise a support case with Salesforce.

Comment: It could be possible that apex best practices were not followed and your scheduled job was processing lesser volume of records in the past, so it probably didn't run into any issue. Have you noticed any recent increase in the volume of records being processed?